# Missing Character

Tags: characters

I was trying to make changes to a template but was running into an issue. You see, it seems the first character (Chinese) was always missing from the first line under the {defn} line.(Like this picture as below)
[image]

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%==Theorems==
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,theorems}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{\thesection}
\makeatletter     
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1pt
\geometry{margin=1in, headsep=0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.39996pt}
% Definition
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=cnt, number within=section]{defn}{Definition}
    {theorem style=theorem wide name and number,breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
    boxrule=0pt,toprule=1pt,leftrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt, rightrule=0pt,left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
    titlerule=0.5em,toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=-0.1cm,top=0.2cm,
    colframe=white!10!coral,colback=white!75!pink,coltitle=white, coltext=bourguignon!80!coral,
    title style={white!10!coral}, before skip=8pt, after skip=8pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{defn}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted the code, commented out the `cnt` business that serves no purpose, unless you need the definition to share the counter with other environments. I commented out also the color choices as I don't want to guess them. What the

```
theorem wide name and number
```

style is I don't know and there's no trace thereof in the `tcolorbox` manual.

You're neglecting the fact that `defn` requires ***two*** arguments: one is the title and the other one is a label for cross-references.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,theorems}

%\newcounter{cnt}
% Definition
\newtcbtheorem[
%  use counter=cnt,
  number within=section
]{defn}{Definition}{
  %theorem style=theorem wide name and number, % <-- ???
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0mm,
  outer arc=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=1pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=1pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  left=0.2cm,
  right=0.2cm,
  titlerule=0.5em,
  toptitle=0.1cm,
  bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
  top=0.2cm,
  %colframe=white!10!coral,
  %colback=white!75!pink,
  coltitle=white,
  %coltext=bourguignon!80!coral,
  %title style={white!10!coral},
  before skip=8pt,
  after skip=8pt,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  fontupper=\normalsize
}{defn}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}{Something}
XYZ
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}{Something}{}
XYZ
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}{Something}{AAAAAA}
XYZ
\end{defn}

\ref{defn:AAAAAA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the first example misses the second argument and so the first following object is taken for it.

Comment: It works! Thank you !!